# Why makefile is not saving output files to different directory?

Tags: makefile, g++, gnu-make

I'm playing with makefile and I have this issue - it's not saving output files to different directories.

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -c -Wall
ODIR = obj
BDIR = bin

$(BDIR)/test: test.o print.o
    $(CC) test.o print.o -o test

$(ODIR)/%.o: %.cpp %.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

.PHONY : clean
clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o $(BDIR)/test
```

Even if I create these directories manually it doesn't work as expected. Both dirs are empty after "make" without any errors. Output files are always created in main directory. Will be gret if you can give me an advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule:

```
$(BDIR)/test: test.o print.o
```

tells make that to build `$(BDIR)/test` it first needs to build `test.o` and `print.o`.  So, it does build those two files.  You have defined a rule to build `$(ODIR)/%.o`, but `test.o` does not match the pattern `$(ODIR)/%.o` so that rule is not used.

Instead make uses its own default built-in rules that know how to create `%.o`; that pattern *DOES* match your target `test.o`.

If you want make to build objects in another directory, you have to list them there when you write your rules:

```
$(BDIR)/test: $(ODIR)/test.o $(ODIR)/print.o
```

Now, make knows you want to build targets in the `$(ODIR)` directory so it will use a rule that can do so.

Comment: Thank you. That was really helpful and I was able to solve this issue.